# fatal error: strtok_r.h: No such file or directory (while compiling tesseract-ocr-3.01 in MinGW)

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, mingw, tesseract

I'm compiling tesseract-ocr-3.01 in MinGW, and I'm getting this error `ambigs.cpp:31:22: fatal error: strtok_r.h: No such file or directory`

This is the code where the error is:

```
#ifdef WIN32
#ifndef __GNUC__
#define strtok_r strtok_s
#else
#include "strtok_r.h"
#endif  /* __GNUC__ */
#endif  /* WIN32 */
```

---

**Edit**

I found this feature request to [add strtok_r.h to MinGW](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=2673480&group_id=2435&atid=352435). From the comments there:

> strtok_r() is an *optional* POSIX function, required only for
>   implementations which support POSIX threads. MinGW does *not* support
>   POSIX threads; therefore, I don't think that this function has any
>   place in a base MinGW distribution.
>
> POSIX threads support for MS-Windows is provided by the pthreads-win32
>   project. Maybe they already provide a strtok_r() implementation. If
>   so, then you could use it; if not, you might ask them to consider
>   adding it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is most easily solved by adding an [strtok_r implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12975180/492336) to the project's sources:

```
char *strtok_r(char *str, const char *delim, char **save)
{
    char *res, *last;

    if( !save )
        return strtok(str, delim);
    if( !str && !(str = *save) )
        return NULL;
    last = str + strlen(str);
    if( (*save = res = strtok(str, delim)) )
    {
        *save += strlen(res);
        if( *save < last )
            (*save)++;
        else
            *save = NULL;
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Indeed, just paste above to ambigs.cpp and it fixes the problem.