# strtok_r for MinGW

Tags: c, mingw, strtok

[strtok_r](http://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man3/strtok_r.3.asp) is the reentrant variant of strtok. It is POSIX-conformant. However, it is missing from MinGW, and I'm trying to compile a program that is using it.

Is there any way I could add a standard implementation of this function, perhaps to the project's own code, or to MinGW's standard library functions?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since there are some license questions about the code from another answer, here's one that's explicitly public domain:

```
/* 
 * public domain strtok_r() by Charlie Gordon
 *
 *   from comp.lang.c  9/14/2007
 *
 *      http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.c/msg/2ab1ecbb86646684
 *
 *     (Declaration that it's public domain):
 *      http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.c/msg/7c7b39328fefab9c
 */

char* strtok_r(
    char *str, 
    const char *delim, 
    char **nextp)
{
    char *ret;

    if (str == NULL)
    {
        str = *nextp;
    }

    str += strspn(str, delim);

    if (*str == '\0')
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    ret = str;

    str += strcspn(str, delim);

    if (*str)
    {
        *str++ = '\0';
    }

    *nextp = str;

    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's the source code which you can simply add to your own library/function in your project:

```
char *strtok_r(char *str, const char *delim, char **save)
{
    char *res, *last;

    if( !save )
        return strtok(str, delim);
    if( !str && !(str = *save) )
        return NULL;
    last = str + strlen(str);
    if( (*save = res = strtok(str, delim)) )
    {
        *save += strlen(res);
        if( *save < last )
            (*save)++;
        else
            *save = NULL;
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: This is the standard implementation of strtok_r. If `str` is a on heap then this is thread-safe.

Comment: Is it reasonable to expect str to be on heap? Meaning, is the requirement part of the spec?

Comment: Is this your own local implementation or did it come from an open source project?  If its the latter, is there any license associated with its use?

Comment: libc source. This is very simple. Anyone can implement without ever looking at the source. I don't think there's any license associated with this.

Comment: Sorry if I'm being dim but do you have a link to the source?  It seems unlikely to me that it'll have been released without any license but I expect I'll be proved wrong :-)

Comment: AFAIK `strtok` stores a statically allocated pointer to the current token. Every time you call `strtok` passing a non-null `delim` you are initializing this pointer, so you may affect another thread that may use `strtok` at the same time... From the OpenGroup specification: "*The strtok() function need not be reentrant. A function that is not required to be reentrant is not required to be thread-safe.*" (http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strtok_r.html). Excuse me if I'm wrong.

Comment: (Continue) Actually, the implementation I posted in my answer does not use `strtok`. Actually, `strtok` is a particular case `strtok_r` that uses the statically allocated pointer I commented.

Answer (score 1):

Is the [FreeBSD implementation](http://svn.freebsd.org/base/user/eri/pf45/head/lib/libc/string/strtok.c) any use to you?

Its liberally licensed but integrating it may have some requirements on your project documentation (adding an acknowledgement that the code has been included).

Answer (score 1):

MINGW has no implementation of `strtok_r`. However you can find a thread-safe implementation in the link below:

http://www.raspberryginger.com/jbailey/minix/html/strtok__r_8c-source.html