# How can I count specific words from a file?

Tags: c

I am trying to create a c program that read a file and count specific words.

I tried this code but I don't get any result:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
void main
{
  File *fp = fopen("file.txt","r+");
  int count =0;
  char ch[10]; 

  while((fgetc(fp)!=NULL)
   {
     while((fgetc(fp)!=NULL)
      {
        if((fgets(ch,3,fp))=="the" || (fgets(ch,3,fp))=="and")
         count++;
      }
   }
   printf("%d",count);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by you don't get any result ? What do you get as output ?

Comment: Please get your code to a state when it at least compiles, this would bring you a lot closer. In addition, you need to re-think your algorithm completely, because the words do not need to appear at a three-character boundaries. Finally, your code does not check that the words appear by themselves, so words like "these" or "stand" would be counted incorrectly.

Comment: I think than the comparison simply because may be included in the string of the other, as it is necessary to cut out the word first.

Comment: To process individual words you should probably use something like strtok or strtok_r. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12975022/strtok-r-for-mingw

Answer (score 1):

As you're acquiring data in blocks of 3 at a time, you're assuming that the two words "the" and "and" are aligned on 3 character boundaries. That will not, in general, be the case.

You also need to use `strncmp` to compare the strings.

As a first review, I'd read line by line and search each line for the words you want.

I'm also unsure as your intention behind having two nested `while` loops.

Answer (score 1):

You can't compare string pointers with the equality operator, you have to use the [`strcmp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp) function.

There are also other problems with the code you have. For once, the `fgetc` calls does not return `NULL` on errors or problems, but `EOF`. Otherwise it returns a character read from the file.

Also, your two `fgets` in the condition will cause reading of two *"lines"* (though each "line" you read will only be two characters) from the file.

Answer (score 1):

`fgets(ch, 3, fp)` makes you read 2 characters plus the null-terminator, if you want to read 3 characters and the null-terminator you want `fgets(ch, 4, fp)` instead. Also, you need to use `strcmp` to compare strings.

Also, what are all those while loops for ?

Answer (score 0):

if((fgets(ch,3,fp))=="the" || (fgets(ch,3,fp))=="and")

The above line is completely useless.
fgets(ch,3,fp)  gets your  word from the file to ch[10] . But you cannot compare that using == .
What I would do is use strcmp and give size 4 in fgets (never forget the \o)

Answer (score 0):

You gotta use [strcmp()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/) to compare two strings. Not relational operators.

Answer (score 0):

Just out of my head (perhaps not the optimal way, but should be pretty easy to read and understand):

```
#define WHITE_SPACE(c) ((c)==' ' || (c)=='\r' || (c)=='\n' || (c)=='\t'))

int CountWords(const char* fileName,int numOfWords,const char words[])
{
    int count = 0;
    FILE* fp = fopen(fileName,"rt");
    fseek(fp,0,SEEK_END);
    int size = ftell(fp);
    fseek(fp,0,SEEK_SET);
    char* buf = new char[size];
    fread(buf,size,1,fp);
    fclose(fp);
    for (int i=0,j; i<size; i=j+1)
    {
        for (j=i; j<size; j++)
        {
            if (WHITE_SPACE(buf[j]))
                break;
        }
        for (int n=0; n<numOfWords; n++)
        {
            int len = strlen(words[n]);
            if (len == j-i && !memcmp(buf+i,words[n],len))
                count++;
        }
    }
    delete[] buf;
    return count;
}
```

Please note, however, that I have not compiled nor tested it (as I said above, "out of my head")...

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [String matching algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_matching).

You can also find implementation examples of [Boyer-Moore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm) in github

Answer (score 0):

The line

> if((fgets(ch,3,fp))=="the" || (fgets(ch,3,fp))=="and")

has a couple of problems:

- You can't compare string values with the `==` operator; you need to use the `strcmp` library function;
- You're not comparing the same input to `"the"` and `"and"`; when the first comparison fails, you're reading the next 3 characters from input;

Life will be easier if you abstract out the input and comparison operations; at a high level, it would look something like this:

```
#define MAX_WORD_LENGTH 10 // or however big it needs to be
...
char word[MAX_WORD_LENGTH + 1];
...
while ( getNextWord( word, sizeof word, fp )) // will loop until getNextWord 
{                                             // returns false (error or EOF)
  if ( match( word ) )
    count++;
}
```

The `getNextWord` function handles all the input; it will read characters from the input stream until it recognizes a "word" or until there's no room left in the input buffer.  In this particular case, we'll assume that a "word" is simply any sequence of non-whitespace characters (meaning punctuation will be counted as part of a word).  If you want to be able to recognize punctuation as well, this gets a bit harder; for example, a `'` may be quoting character ('hello'), in which case it should not be part of the word, or it may be part of a contraction or a posessive (it's, Joe's), in which case it *should* be part of the word.

```
#include <ctype.h>
...
int getNextWord( char *target, size_t targetSize, FILE *fp )
{
  size_t i = 0;
  int c;

  /**
   * Read the next character from the input stream, skipping
   * over any leading whitespace.  We'll add each non-whitespace
   * character to the target buffer until we see trailing 
   * whitespace or EOF.
   */
  while ( (c = fgetc( fp )) != EOF && i < targetSize - 1 )
  {
    if ( isspace( c ) )
    {
      if ( i == 0 )
        continue;
      else
        break;
    }
    else
    {
      target[i++] = c;
    }
  }

  target[i] = 0;      // add 0 terminator to string
  return i > 0;       // if i == 0, then we did not successfully read a word
}
```

The `match` function simply compares the input word to a list of target words, and returns "true" (1) if it sees a match.  In this case, we create a list of target words with a terminating NULL entry; we just walk down the list, comparing each element to our input.  If we reach the NULL entry, we didn't find a match.

```
#include <string.h>
...
int match( const char *word )
{
  const char *targets[] = {"and", "the", NULL};
  const char *t = targets;

  while ( t && strcmp( t, word ))
    t++;

  return t != NULL;  // evaluates to true if we match either "the" or "and"
}
```

Note that this comparison is case-sensitive; "The" will not compare equal to "the".  If you want a case-insensitive comparison, you'll have to make a copy of the input string and convert it all to lowercase, and compare that copy to the target:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#Include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
...
int match( const char *word )
{
  const char *targets[] = {"and", "the", NULL};
  const char *t = targets;

  char *wcopy = malloc( strlen( word ) + 1 );
  if ( wcopy )
  {
    char *w = word;
    char *c = wcopy;

    while ( *w )
      *c++ = tolower( *w++ );
  }
  else
  {
    fprintf( stderr, "malloc failure in match: fatal error, exiting\n" );
    exit(0);
  }

  while ( t && strcmp( t, wcopy))
    t++;

  free( wcopy );
  return t != NULL;  // evaluates to true if we match either "the" or "and"
}
```