# Tesseract 3.03 compile error: 'select' was not declared in this scope

Tags: cygwin, tesseract, python-tesseract

I am using `cygwin` to compile the [Tesseract 3.03 source code](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B7l10Bj_LprhQnpSRkpGMGV2eE0&usp=sharing).

The following error is encountered when I run `make` after `configure`. I have no knowledge to modify the Tesseract source code. Anyone saw this error before? Or is there any prebuilt version of Tessearct 3.03?  I need this very version because it contains the training tools `text2image` and they claim it can be built with `make training`.

[image]

### ADD 1

Below is the code snippet in trouble.

[image]

It seems to me the `select` function is a C++ library function. Maybe some library is missing on my Cygwin installation. But I am not sure which one.

### ADD 2

Following `rubenvb`'s suggestion on this thread:[Error during making "xz-5.2.1" with MinGW/MSYS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29960825/error-during-making-xz-5-2-1-with-mingw-msys)

I start to use `MSYS2 + MinGW-w64` to compile `Tesseract 3.03`. After fighting through all the dependencies and pre-requisites. I finally successfully `configure` the `Tesseract 3.03 source`. And then encountered the following error during `make`:

[image]

I found a similar thread: [fatal error: strtok_r.h: No such file or directory (while compiling tesseract-ocr-3.01 in MinGW)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12973750/fatal-error-strtok-r-h-no-such-file-or-directory-while-compiling-tesseract-oc)

It seems I need to manually add some file to the tesseract source. But I am not sure where to place it.

For now I need to take some sleep.

Hope someone could shed some light on this issue. I will continue with it tomorrow...

### Reference

Compile Tesseract 3.03 with vs2013

http://vorba.ch/2014/tesseract-3.03-vs2013.html

Compile Tesseract 3.02 with Cygwin

http://vorba.ch/2014/tesseract-cygwin.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally complete the compilation in a full Linux environment.

Answer (score 0):

Found a tutorial [here](http://vorba.ch/2014/tesseract-cygwin.html).
As said in the comments:

> Try to replace "c++11" with "gnu++11" in the file "configure", then rerun this script.

Comment: You are so amazing! That comment looks very promising. I will give it a shot and update later.

Comment: Unfortunately, I did as the comment said. But the error still remains.